# CGRectIntersectsRect working inconsistently

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have code that generates a random CGRect, checks to see if it intersects any other rects in a previous array, and if it doesn't it adds the new rect to the array. This works perfectly fine, however I also want to ensure that the random CGRect also doesn't overlap an image in the center of the screen. I created a rect that outlines the image with plenty of extra space on the sides, but while the random CGRects still don't intersect each other, they will sometimes intersect the center image rect.

```
CGRect aRandomFrame = CGRectMake((aRandomX - 50), (aRandomY - 50), 100, 100);
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake((self.fixation.center.x - 50), (self.fixation.center.y - 50), 100, 100);

if (CGRectContainsRect(BOUNDARY, aRandomFrame)) {
    BOOL isValidFrame = YES;
    for (NSValue *aFrameValue in [self points]) {
        CGRect aFrame = [aFrameValue CGRectValue];
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(aFrame, aRandomFrame) || CGRectIntersectsRect(imageRect, aRandomFrame)) {
            isValidFrame = NO;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isValidFrame) {
        [[self points] addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:aRandomFrame]];
    }
}
```

As a sidenote, BOUNDARY is a larger rect to make sure that none of the random rects are too far from the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convince a reader that `CGRectIntersectsRect` isn't working, you'd need to present some NSLog evidence showing it failing.

The code looks okay, so the suspicion falls things we can't see in the OP:

1. The computation of `aRandomX` and `aRandomY`.  I presume that looks something like this:

   ```
   CGFloat aRandomX = arc4random_uniform(someView.bounds.size.width);
   CGFloat aRandomY = arc4random_uniform(someView.bounds.size.height);
   ```

**someView** is important here:  it is a `UIView` containing the image view and the coordinate system of all of these rects, possibly `self.view` if we're within a view controller

2. The value of `BOUNDARY`, but I bet that's a simple constant rectangle with a zero or small origin and a size equal or a little smaller than `someView`
3. The probable and most sinister culprit is the coordinate system of the `imageRect`.  If the rectangle and boundary are in the coordinate system of **someView** then so must be the center property of `self.fixation`.  In other words `self.fixation` must be a direct subview of `someView`.

No matter how it relates to someView in the view hierarchy, you can insure that `imageRect` is correct by using a slightly more sophisticated approach:

```
CGRect imageRect = [self.fixation convertRect:self.fixation.bounds toView:someView];
// remember someView might be self.view in a view controller
// what to do here depends on how your view hierarchy relates to the rects
```

As a side note, your loop is a little wasteful, since it makes the imageRect check every time when checking the computed rect against the saved ones.  You can fix that like this:

```
if (CGRectContainsRect(BOUNDARY, aRandomFrame)) {
    if (!CGRectIntersectsRect(imageRect, aRandomFrame)) {
        BOOL isDisjoint = YES;
        for (NSValue *frameValue in self.points) {
            CGRect aFrame = [frameValue CGRectValue];
            if (CGRectIntersectsRect(aFrame, aRandomFrame)) {
                isDisjoint = NO;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isDisjoint) {
            [self.points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:aRandomFrame]];
        }
    }
}
```

Another benefit of this is for debugging: break inside that second conditional and check to see if `aRandomFrame` intersects `imageRect`.  If it does, NSLog the rectangles and post them here. You will have made a huge discovery that `CGRectContainsRect` has a bug, *but it doesn't, I am certain*.

Instead, if you'll see that the rectangles don't intersect at that point, and if anything is wrong, it will be with the `imageRect`.  Good luck!

Comment: Sorry this response is so late, other things demanded my attention and this got put on the back burner. But I implemented what you put and it helped me troubleshoot some issues, so thank you!